# Ignore backup files in chrome debugger source tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome DevTools and have mapped my local source tree.  As a result, when I look in the Filesystem tab in the Sources tab, I can see all of my source files and all of my backup files.

The backup files are pure clutter: is there a way to hide them from the view?

I am not talking about black boxing: that prevents me from stepping into files that are actually used.  I want to not see files that are not used in the list of files.

[image: Source file listing]

I want `model.jsx.~1~` to not show up in this case.  In general, any file matching `*~` should be hidden.

Comment: Devtools can only exclude folders from the file system workspace. You can submit a feature request to extend it to files too on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Added.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883325

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the comments, this is not currently possible.  I created an issue to request the ability.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883325